# Is SSTables or Hfiles merged above 1TB?

Tags: cassandra, hbase, bigtable

In major compaction merge all sstables from region server (Hbase) and all SSTables form tablet server (Cassandra) into big one.

If period comes is meany SSTables (total space above 1TB) merged into one?
Maby there is some range bounds for SSTable or HFile that splits it to several parts - for ensure that merge operations dont "rewrite all server"?

My question is related to "Compaction" section of this link http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable

Answer (score 1):

From what I found actually SSTable producted by major compaction is not splited in Cassandra. Other LSM-tree databases relies in this case on disturbed file system whitch splits SSTable (or HFile, CellSotre in Hypertable) into several files (for example 64MB) but major compaction either must compact all of this file into new one SSTable (i think is inefficient).

There are tickets in JIRA to improve and redesign compaction for Cassandra as mentioned:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1608

You may also want read my second simiral question:

[How much data per node in Cassandra cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775388/how-much-data-per-node-in-cassandra-cluster)