# Cassandra cluster planning

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, cassandra-3.0

I would like to know about hardware limitations in cluster planning (in TBs) specific to my use case. I have read few threads and documents related to it but some content seem to be over 5 years old. Thought of giving it a shot again:

**Use case:** *Building a time-series cassandra cluster where there is from time-to-time bulk loading from data sources which are in Gigabytes. However, the end-user will majorly be focused in reading the data from the cluster. Quite rarely will be some update or delete on the rows*

I have an initial hardware configuration with me to setup Cassandra cluster:

- 2*12 Cores
- 128 GB RAM
- HDD SAS 3.27 TB

This is the initial plan that I come up with: [image]

When I now speculate over the setup, and after reading the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775388/how-much-data-per-node-in-cassandra-cluster):
should I further divide my nodes with lesser RAM, vCPUs and HDD?
If yes, what would be the good fit wrt my case?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningHardware.html  http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningHardware_c.html

Comment: Better avoid VM hardware for Cassandra